# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CalledProcessError'

Tags: python, attributeerror

I have read through every single question on this topic, and have still been unable to resolve this issue. The most frustrating thing about this is that this is not occurring in one of my scripts, but rather in a 3rd-party library (Naked). Here is *my* code:

```
import Naked.toolshed.shell as shell
#skip a few lines
respondedSuccessfully = shell.execute_js("notifications.js", token)
```

Here is Naked's `execute_js` function:

```
import subprocess
#skip a few lines
def execute_js(file_path, arguments=""):
try:
    if len(arguments) > 0:
        js_command = 'node ' + file_path + " " + arguments
    else:
        js_command = 'node ' + file_path
    return execute(js_command) # return result of execute() of node.js file
except Exception as e:
    if DEBUG_FLAG:
         sys.stderr.write("Naked Framework Error: unable to run the shell command with the run_js() function (Naked.toolshed.shell.py).")
    raise e
```

So far, so good. Here is the `execute()` function that it calls:

```
def execute(command):
try:
    response = subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
    if response == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as cpe:
    try:
        sys.stderr.write(cpe.output)
    except TypeError as te:
        sys.stderr.write(str(cpe.output))
except Exception as e:
    if DEBUG_FLAG:
        sys.stderr.write("Naked Framework Error: unable to run the shell command with the execute() function (Naked.toolshed.shell.py).")
    raise e
```

When I execute my code, it throws the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CalledProcessError'
```

I do not have a file named "subprocess", and executing those lines one-by-one works. I am stumped. [Here](https://github.com/chrissimpkins/naked) is the Naked library.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you do `import subprocess`, can you access `subprocess.CalledProcessError`? Can you double check that `subprocess.__file__` points to the standard library, not somewhere unexpected?

Comment: Nope, running from standard library, as expected, from the .pyc file.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? I don't see that exception documented prior to version 2.7 and 3.2, though none of the versions that list it say when it was introduced (with a `new in version X.Y` line).

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.9

Comment: To clarify, are you able to access `subprocess.CalledProcessError` when to import `subprocess` yourself?

Comment: Well, it's an exception, but I do see it as output when I do `dir(subprocess)`